# Azure web site WebResource.axd return 404 error or 500 error

Tags: asp.net, azure

I migrated an asp.net 2.0 application to asp.net 4.5.

Tested it locally with iis express, everything worked fine

But when i uploaded to azure web sites, i got an issue.  The website used some asp controls, like asp:TreeView,  so there will be some WebResource.axd requests.

Now from the azure, all the WebResource.axd requests will fail with 404 error.

I tried add the handler in web.config, that doesn't help, it will actually return 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the managed pipeline mode from classic to integrated, that fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution still working in classic mode. Just add a handler at web.config

```
<handlers>

  <add name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />

</handlers>
```

Take a look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/52c20847-7558-4507-9d55-2620a98fb0a1/webresourceaxd-and-scriptresourceaxd-404-error?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview